# Unknown Error on Remote Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api running on a remote server that I connect to over VPN in order to deploy updates.

I installed the Rewrite Module for IIS 7 and made a rule to rewrite http to https for all requests.

Suddenly I am getting this error when I attempt to acquire an authorization token (OAuth):

```
{
 "error":"server_error",
 "error_description":"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
}
```

And this message for any api endpoint:

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on. How can I get a more useful error message from asp.net or iis? I cannot do remote debugging and the server does not have visual studio installed.

I have undone all the modifications I made and its still broken.

Comment: Have you tried checking the application and event logs on the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a sign that IIS is having problems even starting the application.  I'd remove everything from the web.config file and add each line in one by one until you get back to this error message.  If it is an application error (i.e., something in your code) you would get a 500.  Since you aren't getting a 500, it is a lower level than your application and the next lower level is IIS parsing your web.config file before serving requests.